# react-native console.log inside componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The root component in a very straightforward app ...
Any debugging code put in `componentWillUnmount` is not shown in debugger-window

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      console.log('Will unmount - cleanup...'); // not logged
    },
    []
  );
};
```

Why's that?
And How can I debug that cleanup code...

Comment: Reproducible example? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Remove one of the `() =>`

Comment: @JoyTerence That weird syntax means the returned function by `useEffect` ... used for cleanup

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Logic to run on mounting and update  

    return () = {
        // Clean up code
        console.log('------');  // this will log every time when component unmounts
    }
}, [dependency array]);
```

`[]` is the dependency array, if blank `useEffect()` will run on mounting only and its clean up function will execute every time. If the array have some value in it, then whenever that value change, `useEffect()` will again executes.

Comment: Returning a function from an `effect` that has an empty array of `deps` ... simulates exactly ---> class-bassed-component > `componentWillUnmount` event ... I mean what I'm having in my question is intentional

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the first `() =>`.

Also, as an idea, your use effect will render just on the first render of the page, that's what it does when you send an empty array `[]` as argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... but that double () => is intentional ... I wanna debug the cleanup-code which has to run **when the whole app is about to unmount**

Comment: Hmmm, okay pretty interesting, didn't know that. Everyday we learn something :D 
Thank you